# Haskell tail recusion for multi call function

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

Here is non tail recursive function

```
alg :: Int -> Int
alg n = if n<7 then n else alg(n-1) * alg(n-2) * alg(n-4) * alg(n-6)
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, I get the basic idea of tail recursion, and how to do it for single call recursive function, but no clue how to do it for multi call one.

Even came up with this abomination

```
algT :: Int -> Int
algT n = tail1 n 0 where tail1 i r = tail1(i-1) r *
         tail2 n 0 where tail2 i r = tail2(i-2) r *
         tail3 n 0 where tail3 i r = tail3(i-4) r *
         tail4 n 0 where tail4 i r = tail4(i-6) r
```

It doesnt work and obviously not how recursive function should look, had few other attempts, but all of them ended in infinite 100% cpu load loop...

Comment: I'm not even sure there is a way to make this strictly tail recursive.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It seems to me that it should be possible to get elements of any sequence that you can generate with a loop tail recursively.

Comment: Right.  You have to change the algorithm entirely, though, it's not just a simple transformation.

Comment: You can always do "tail recursion" the question is whether you are doing tail recursion with a manual stack (which defeats the purpose).

Comment: Looking at the original code, and barring the possibility of a mathematical closed form for that, I would try to apply memoization (to achieve dynamic programming) rather than using tail recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it's not entirely clear what is the purpose of making your function tail-recusrive. If you are trying to reduce cpu/memory usage, then you should use memoization (mentioned in the Guvante's answer).

Meanwhile, there is a way to make almost any function tail-recursive, known as [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Your example written in the CPS looks like this:

```
alg_cps :: Integer -> (Integer->a) -> a
alg_cps n cont = 
    if n < 7 
    then cont n 
    else alg_cps (n - 1) 
        (\x1 -> alg_cps (n - 2) 
            (\x2 -> alg_cps (n - 4) 
                (\x3 -> alg_cps (n - 6)
                    (\x4 -> cont (x1*x2*x3*x4)))))
```

And to directly get the result you can call it with `id` as continuation:

```
alg_cps 20 id
```

Notice that this does not reduce algorithm complexity or memory usage compared to naive non-tail recursive implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into Fibonacci in Haskell? It is a similar type of function. BTW tail recursion isn't quite the right term in Haskell, as multi-recursion functions can't really be done recursively but Haskell's lazy nature makes a similar but more powerful trick possible. Here is the standard one given:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Using the same trick on yours gives EDIT: As a function

```
alg :: Int -> Int
alg n = alg' !! (n - 1)
    where alg' = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : zipWith4 (\a b c d -> a * b * c * d) (drop 5 alg') (drop 4 alg') (drop 2 alg') alg'
```

Note that you shouldn't use `Int` here, that isn't open ended and the 11th term will loop in an `Int`.

EDIT: Actually `Int` is even worse than I thought. Once you hit 32 2's in your result you will start returning 0 since every answer is 0 mod 2^32.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, but it's not very elegant or pretty.

```
alg :: Int -> Int
alg n | n < 7     -> n
      | otherwise -> alg' n (repeat 0)

alg' :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
alg' n [] = error "something has gone horribly wrong"
alg' n l@(x:y)
  | n < 5     -> error "something else has gone horribly wrong"
  | n == 6    -> product $ zipWith (^) [6,5..1] l
  | otherwise -> alg' (n-1) $ zipWith (+) [x,x,0,x,0,x] (y ++ [0])
```

The idea is that you can keep track of how many times you're supposed to be multiplying each thing without actually doing any of the calculations until the very end. At any given time, you have information about how many times you've needed any of the next 6 values, and once you're below 7, you just raise 1-6 to the proper powers and take their product.

(I haven't actually tested this, but it seems right. And even if it's not I'm pretty sure the idea behind it is sound)

P.S. As @Guvante says, `Int` isn't a good choice here as it will quickly overflow. As a general rule I use `Integer` by default and only switch if I have a good reason.

Comment: Isn't `**` exponentiation of `Floating`?

Comment: Yep, noticed that integer limits overflows very fast, but this is an assignment and thus I cannot change declarations and have to use Int, even though we are told to run alg (20) and 50 and compare, when it dies on 12 and is incredibly slow on higher numbers while returning zero..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```
let f = [1..6] ++ foldr1 (zipWith (*)) [f, drop 2 f, drop 4 f, drop 5 f]
```

or even:

```
let f = [1..6] ++ foldr1 (zipWith (*)) (map (flip drop $ f) [0,2,4,5])
```

Comment: How would one use this solution, I am having hard time wrapping my head around it